# Kotlin unresolved reference when using mutlithreading

Tags: multithreading, kotlin

So I'm trying to use kotlin together with selenium and threading, but one parameter doesnt work. Here's my code:

```
class myClass(parameter1 : String, parameter2 : String, parameter3 : Int) : Thread(){
    init{
        var driver : ChromeDriver = ChromeDriver()
    }
    override fun run() {
        driver.get("somewebsite")
        var id_field = driver.findElementByName("iD")
        id_field.sendKeys(parameter1)
        id_field.submit()
        name = parameter2 + parameter3.toString()
        //At this Point, Intellij Idea tells me: Unresolved reference: parameter3
        name_field = driver.findElementByName("name")
        name_field.sendKeys(name)
        name_field.submit()


        }
}

fun main() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver")
        val threads: Array<myClass> = Array(2) { myClass("some_id", "name", it)}

    }
```

What should happen is that the script goes to my website, enters the name and iD. But I want to be able to run mutiple threads of my script where the threads "iteration" (which is parameter 3) is being added to my name.

So for example:
- thread 1 logs in with: name1
- thread 2 logs in with: name2
(...)
- thread 20 logs in with: name20

But my question is:
Why doesnt kotlin say: Unsolved reference: parameter 3?

Comment: `parameter3` is just an (unused) constructor parameter. If you want to store it in the class you need to change the class declaration to `myClass(...., val parameter3 : Int) ...`